# I want to determine the Eigen values of this matrix. How?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

$$ 
%\left[  \begin{array}{c} c_0 \\ c_1 \\ c_2 \\ \vdots \\ c_{2m-1} \end{array} \right] = 
 \left[  \begin{array}{ccccc} 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\ 1 & \zeta & \zeta^2 & \cdots & \zeta^{2m-1} \\
 1& \zeta^2 & \zeta^4 &  \cdots & \zeta^{4m-2}  \\ \vdots &\vdots &  \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
  1 & \zeta^{2m-1} & \zeta^{4m-2} & \cdots & \zeta^{(2m-1)^2} \end{array} \right]
% \left[  \begin{array}{c} y_0 \\ y_1 \\ y_2 \\ \vdots \\ y_{2m-1} \end{array} \right]
,$$

where $$\zeta \colon= e^{\pi i/ m}$$.

What are the eigenvalues of this Vandermonde matrix?

Comment: Are you looking for a numerical approximation or an exact answer?  What have you done so far?

Comment: I have no idea. I'm pretty sure they are exact values. I tried taking $$det(A-\lambda I)$$ but that was a fail. I shall try another approach . This matrix $V$ is used to compute the coefficients $c_k$ of the Fast Fourier Transform $S_m$, $$c^T=V\cdot y^T$$ where $y^T$ are the values of $f(x)$ evaluated at $x_j=-\pi+j*\pi/m$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors